# Returning a forwarded reference

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to build a maximum function that forwards the larger value to the result, keeping the type of reference (rvalue or lvalue).

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
constexpr T&& mmax(T&& left, T&& right) {
    return left > right ? std::forward<T>(left) : std::forward<T>(right);
}

int main() {
    mmax(1, 2);
}
```

However, this gives me

```
max.cc: In instantiation of 'constexpr T&& mmax(T&&, T&&) [with T = int]':
max.cc:9:14:   required from here
max.cc:5:72: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return left > right ? std::forward<T>(left) : std::forward<T>(right);
```

Why is that? I'm using GCC 4.8.2 with -std=c++11.

**Edit**: This does not happen with clang++.

Comment: How about `return std::forward<T>(left > right ? left : right)`?

Comment: what compiler are you using? I have not this warning using Apple LLVM 5.0

Comment: This is odd, anyway - you can't really have a universal reference for *multiple* parameters.

Comment: @kerreksb sure you can, it just is not that useful!

Comment: `int&&` issue of some kind?  Try it with `struct test{bool operator<(test)const{return true;};};` instead of `int`

Comment: @KevinMOLCARD GCC 4.8.2, I updated the question

Comment: @KerrekSB I want all arguments to be the same kind of reference, so the return type is unambigous. Why is having the same universal reference multiple times a bad thing?

Comment: @Yakk: That does not change anything, unfortuanely.

Comment: @trion: It sort of defeats the purpose: A universal reference should always be a reference, and it chooses lvalue or rvalue type depending on the provided argument. That logic doesn't generalize to multiple arguments. You might "get what you think" if all participating arguments of same kind, or you might get a deduction failure, or you might silently bind an rvalue to a const lvalue reference...

Comment: @KerrekSB Is there a way to force both references into the same type? I think I could use `std::remove_reference`, but then I'd need overloads for lvalue/rvalue types.

Comment: @KerrekSB Actually, `return std::forward<T>(left > right ? left : right)` does the trick. So `?:` is causing the rvalue reference to degrade, isn't it? If you explain it in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @trion: A standard way to deduce one parameter and force another to have the same type is to make the second type non-deducible, like so: `template <typename T> void foo(T && a1, typename std::common_type<T>::type a2)` Now `a1` is bound by universal reference, and `a2` must be able to match that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original code should work, because of the rules about the conditional operator in C++ 11 5.16/4:

> If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result is of that type and value category

The two expressions `forward<T>(left)` and `forward<T>(right)` are either both lvalues or both xvalues, so they are always glvalues, and they are both of type `T`, and so the rule applies, and the type of the conditional expression should be of the same type and value category.

However, as a workaround for a potential compiler bug, you can use the following expression, which avoids figuring out the type and value category of the conditional expression (which seems to be where the bug is):

```
return std::forward<T>(left > right ? left : right);
```

Comment: The danger above is that if conversion was done, you now silently return a reference to a trmporary.   Consider returning a `T` if you take a `T&&`, it enables reference lifetime extension as well.

Comment: @Yakk: Well, it's hard to argue about what a non-conforming compiler will do. We know that `left` and `right` are both references, so there shouldn't be any temporaries, but who knows?

Comment: @Kerrek: Why couldn't there be temporaries?  It's only non-const lvalue references that won't bind to temporaries, and this function accepts both const lvalue references and rvalue references.

Comment: @BenVoigt: But those aren't temporaries created by the function. They're the caller's responsibility.

Comment: Examine `auto&& x=mmax(exp1,exp2);`  if exp1 or 2 are temporaries, things go poorly.  You very rarely want to return a `T&&`  - return a `T` and things go well.

Comment: @Yakk: Yeah, I know you can abuse this, but the OP seems to be aware of that, since she proposed the original design.